# ASP.NET : App_Code Class files not getting updated after modification

Tags: asp.net, deployment, app-code

I have an ASP.NET web site where i am having App_code folder in which i put my class files (Business objects). Its running fine.But when i made some changes in the class (Added few proprties /Methods) and uploaded to the webserver (in production) its not getting affected in the live site.But this works pretty good when runs in local(so there is no code error).Is this because the DLLS are dynamically generated in the live server and not getting updated  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile and publish your application using the 'Publish' option in Visual Studio.

Thanks,

Phil.